# Definition of ellipsoid

Tags: convex-analysis, ellipsoids

In chapter 2 section 2.2.2 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/), the definition of an ellipsoid (which is a convex set) is given as the

$$
\mathcal{E} = \left\{x \mid (x - x_c)^{\intercal} P^{-1} (x - x_c) \le 1 \right\}
$$

where $P = P^\intercal $ is symmetric and positive definite and $x_c$ is the center.

---

If we restrict to real matrices, the way I understand is:

Symmetric real matrices are always diagonalizable, so $P = RSR^\intercal$ where $R$ is an orthogonal matrix (rotation) with eigenvectors in the columns, and $S$ is a scaling matrix composed of the eigenvalues in the diagonals.

So if we multiply all points in the ellipsoid by the inverse of $P$, we get a circle (by undoing the rotation and scaling). And the condition for a point $x$ to be in the sphere with center $x_c$ is that the squared length of $(x - x_c) \le 1$. All in all, $x$ should be a point in the ellipsoid if

$$
x'^\intercal x' \le 1
$$

where
$$
x' = P^{-1}(x - x_c)
$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$. So $x'^T = (x - x_c)^T(P^{-1})^T$. Thus the correct formula must be

$$(x - x_c)^T(P^{-1})^TP^{-1}(x - x_c) \leq 1$$

But notice that there's no reason you had to call that first matrix $P$. Instead, let's call $P$ the inverse of that matrix in the middle - so what was "$(P^{-1})^TP^{-1}$" is now just called "$P^{-1}$".

That also explains why $P$ has to be positive-definite!

Comment: I see. This made me the look up the "A = R^T R" definition of positive definite matrices. Thanks.